# order of permutation $(2,9,6,3,7)(4,8)$ in $S_9$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, symmetric-groups

In $S_9$ I want to find the order for the permutation $(2,9,6,3,7)(4,8)$

My result is that the order should be 8. 
Wolfram Alpha tells me instead that it is 10.

**Question**: Why is the order of the given permutation 10?

According to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231143/finding-the-order-of-permutations-in-s-8) I have done following:

$$ord \pi := min{\{ k \in \mathbb N | \pi^{k} = id_x\}}$$

so: 
$$ord((2,9,6,3,7)(4,8)) = lcm(n,m)$$
for:
$$(2,9,6,3,7)^n=(1)  \quad \& \quad (4,8)^m=(1)$$

for $(4,8)^n = (1):$
$${   \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix} } \cdot {\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 8 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix} } $$

$$={\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix} } \quad n = 2$$

for $(2,9,6,3,7)^m = (1):$

$$ {\pi^0: \quad}{ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 9 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 6 \\
        \end{pmatrix}}$$

$$ {\pi^1: \quad}{ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 6 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 8 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}}$$

$$ {\pi^2: \quad}{ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 7 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 3 & 8 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}}$$

$$ {\pi^3: \quad}{ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 3 & 9 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 7 \\
        \end{pmatrix}}$$

$$ {\pi^4: \quad}{ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
        1 & 9 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 8 & 6 \\
        \end{pmatrix}} \quad m = 4$$

So according to:

> So the order of σσ is exactly the smallest natural number n such that
>   $(4,5)n=(1)(4,5)n=(1) and (2,3,7)n=(1)$$(2,3,7)n$$=(1)$ (think about this
>   fact for a moment).

The order should be $n \cdot m = 2 \cdot 4$

Comment: The order is $\;10\;$ : the product of the orders of the two cycles whose product is the permutation, because these cycles are *disjoint*

Comment: You wrote the wrong exponents, where you wrote $\pi^0$, it's actually $\pi^1$ etc. So $\pi^5 = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Some advice. When you have permutations written in cycle notation you should use that representation to do the arithmetic. The two line version is much harder to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation of the powers of $(2\;9\;6\;3\;7)$ is wrong. $\pi^0$ is always the *identity permutation*; only $\pi^1$ will be the cycle you have written down.

What you write as $\pi^0$ is actually $\pi$ itself; what you claim is $\pi^1$ is $\pi^2$, and what you claim is $\pi^2$ actually seems to be $\pi^4$; it looks like you're *squaring* each line to get the next line, instead of multiplying it by the original $(2\;9\;6\;3\;7)$.

Thus, the order of the 5-cycle should be $5$, not $4$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sigma=(2~9~6~3~7)$ and $\phi = (4~8)$. Thus $ord(\phi)=2$ and $ord(\sigma)=5$

So $gcd(ord(\phi),ord(\sigma))=1$. Hence $ord(\phi\sigma)=ord(\phi) \cdot ord(\sigma)=2 \cdot 5 = 10$