# efficient way to calculate $\tau \circ \sigma^5 \circ \tau$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, symmetric-groups

let $\tau =  (1,12)(2,11)(3,10)(4,9)(5,8)(6,7)$
$\sigma = (1,4,12,11,8)(3,9,5,10)$

I have to calculate $\tau \circ \sigma^5 \circ \tau$.
**Question:** Is there a more efficient way to calculate that than doing each composition?

I thought that I could do some calculation optimazation according to that [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231143/finding-the-order-of-permutations-in-s-8). But $\tau$ has the order $20$ so it does not help..

Comment: The order of $\tau$ is $2$ and $\tau(123)\tau^{-1}=(\tau(1)\tau(2)\tau(3))$.

Comment: note that $\sigma^5 = (3,9,5,10)$.

Comment: @bfhaha can you explain it a bit more detailed, please? Wolfram alpha returns $(1,12)(2,11)(3,4,5,9,8,10)(6,7)$. I see there must be a link but I cannot explain it...

Comment: $\tau(1)\overset{\tau^{-1}}\to 1\overset{\sigma}\to \sigma(1) \overset{\tau}\to \tau(\sigma(1))$, so, say, if $1$ is mapped by $\sigma$ to $2$, then $\tau(1)$ is mapped by $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ to $\tau(2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the identity $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\tau(i_1,i_2, ...,i_n)\tau^{-1}=(\tau(i_1),\tau(i_2),...,\tau(i_n))$ directly or figure it out by the following commutative diagram.

\begin{align*}
i & \stackrel{\tau}{\rightarrow} \tau(i)\\
\sigma\downarrow & ~~~~~~~\downarrow\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} \\
j & \stackrel{\tau}{\rightarrow} \tau(j)\\
\end{align*}

As Abstraction says, 
$\sigma^5=(3, 9, 5, 10)$.
Note that $\tau^2=1$ and $\tau^{-1}=\tau$.
So 
$$\tau\sigma^5\tau
=\tau(3,9,5,11)\tau
=\tau(3,9,5,11)\tau^{-1}
=(\tau(3),\tau(9),\tau(5),\tau(11)).$$